# SQL sampling of quantum values

Tags: php, mysql, group-by

The question arose sample of quanta values. The situation is:

There is a table payment (payments):

```
id_user[int] 
sum [int] 
date[date]
```

`sum (amount)` can be on any from **0 to 100,000** for example.

I need to group the data output by the sum of the quantum of **50 coins**.

```
For example:

0- 49  coins - paid 14 people.
50-99 coins - 59 users
100-150       - 147, etc. 
to the end (to 100,000)
```

In another way, I can not formulate the task.

I need to establish **SQL-query** (or if use **php**)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT (FLOOR(p.sum / 50) + 1) * 50 payment, COUNT(*) num_users 
FROM payments p
GROUP BY FLOOR(p.sum/50);
```